# CRC4 Implementation in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, crc

I have tried to modify a CRC 8 implementation for 4 bytes but it doesn't work. And I can't find the error.

```
$crc4_table = array(
        0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9, 0x5, 0x2, 0xb, 0xc, 0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3, 0xf, 0x8, 0x1, 0x6,
        0xd, 0xa, 0x3, 0x4, 0x8, 0xf, 0x6, 0x1, 0x7, 0x0, 0x9, 0xe, 0x2, 0x5, 0xc, 0xb,
        0x3, 0x4, 0xd, 0xa, 0x6, 0x1, 0x8, 0xf, 0x9, 0xe, 0x7, 0x0, 0xc, 0xb, 0x2, 0x5,
        0xe, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7, 0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2, 0x4, 0x3, 0xa, 0xd, 0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8,
        0x6, 0x1, 0x8, 0xf, 0x3, 0x4, 0xd, 0xa, 0xc, 0xb, 0x2, 0x5, 0x9, 0xe, 0x7, 0x0,
        0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2, 0xe, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7, 0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8, 0x4, 0x3, 0xa, 0xd,
        0x5, 0x2, 0xb, 0xc, 0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9, 0xf, 0x8, 0x1, 0x6, 0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3,
        0x8, 0xf, 0x6, 0x1, 0xd, 0xa, 0x3, 0x4, 0x2, 0x5, 0xc, 0xb, 0x7, 0x0, 0x9, 0xe,
        0xc, 0xb, 0x2, 0x5, 0x9, 0xe, 0x7, 0x0, 0x6, 0x1, 0x8, 0xf, 0x3, 0x4, 0xd, 0xa,
        0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8, 0x4, 0x3, 0xa, 0xd, 0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2, 0xe, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7,
        0xf, 0x8, 0x1, 0x6, 0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3, 0x5, 0x2, 0xb, 0xc, 0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9,
        0x2, 0x5, 0xc, 0xb, 0x7, 0x0, 0x9, 0xe, 0x8, 0xf, 0x6, 0x1, 0xd, 0xa, 0x3, 0x4,
        0xa, 0xd, 0x4, 0x3, 0xf, 0x8, 0x1, 0x6, 0x0, 0x7, 0xe, 0x9, 0x5, 0x2, 0xb, 0xc,
        0x7, 0x0, 0x9, 0xe, 0x2, 0x5, 0xc, 0xb, 0xd, 0xa, 0x3, 0x4, 0x8, 0xf, 0x6, 0x1,
        0x9, 0xe, 0x7, 0x0, 0xc, 0xb, 0x2, 0x5, 0x3, 0x4, 0xd, 0xa, 0x6, 0x1, 0x8, 0xf,
        0x4, 0x3, 0xa, 0xd, 0x1, 0x6, 0xf, 0x8, 0xe, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7, 0xb, 0xc, 0x5, 0x2);

    $crc = 0xff;
    for ($ii1 = 0; $ii1 < strlen($data); $ii1++) {
        $crc = $crc4_table[($crc ^ ($data[$ii1]))];
    }
    $result = $crc ^ 0xff;
    return dechex($result);
```

I have generated a `crc4_table` and modified the code but these doesn't work. Have anyone any idea or had a working Example for `CRC4` in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yeah but  I can't figure it out yet

Comment: What CRC-4 do you need? Do you have a test string and expected CRC-4 from that string?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial CRC can't be `0xff`. For a 4-bit CRC it needs to be a 4-bit value. E.g. `0xf`. The returned CRC also needs to be four bits, but your `^ 0xff` will always make it eight bits with a high nybble of `f`. The final exclusive-or would need to be `^ 0xf`.

There are many different CRC-4's that could be defined. If you used `0` as the initial CRC value instead of `0xf` and did not invert at the end with `0xf`, then you would get the standard ITU CRC-4.

Comment: Thanks man i need a ccitt crc 4 bit witch Values are here the right ones?

Comment: This is my Input String "01312EA1F0607000612" and the expected Result is "8"

Comment: That's an odd number of hexadecimal digits in the message. Your code operates on bytes, so your message needs to have an even number of digits.

Comment: I prevent a 0 "001312EA1F0607000612" that changes Nothing. The Value is 14 not 8. I don´t get it why this is so

Comment: I can't find any reference to a CCITT CRC-4. Do you have a link? How do you know the CRC should be 8? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: That's an 8-bit CRC, not a 4-bit CRC.